# Mapping a list-like JSON object to a Java list with Jackson

Tags: java, jackson

a third party API I'm using returns the following structure

```
    "openingTimes": {
      "0": {
        "end": {
          "date": "2018-02-05 13:00:00.000000",
          "timezone_type": 1,
          "timezone": "+01:00"
        },
        "start": {
          "date": "2018-02-05 08:00:00.000000",
          "timezone_type": 1,
          "timezone": "+01:00"
        }
      },
      "1": {
        "end": {
          "date": "2018-02-05 18:30:00.000000",
          "timezone_type": 1,
          "timezone": "+01:00"
        },
        "start": {
          "date": "2018-02-05 15:00:00.000000",
          "timezone_type": 1,
          "timezone": "+01:00"
        }
      }
      // more entries
    }
```

Effectively, `openingTimes` is a list of objects but for unknown reasons the API gives me an object where the key is the index and the value the object at that index.

Does Jackson support mapping such a structure to a Java list, e.g.  `List<OpeningTime> openingTimes`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33316577/parsing-json-array-with-numbers-as-keys-using-jackson

Comment: What I can suggest is using a HashMap<String, {Your Class Object}> for the contents inside openingTimes. GSON Supports it, I have used it in one of my projects. This maybe there in Jackson as well.

Comment: This is indeed a duplicate of the answer in the links above